# NodeJS - fs.stat() is ignored in a FOR-loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop

I'm trying to loop over a bunch of directories and then try if a file inside that directory exists with NodeJS and fs.stat().

I've got a simple for-loop to loop over the directories and in it the fs.stat() call to check, if "project.xml" inside that particular directory exists. My code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0, length = prDirs.length; i < length; i++) {
  var path = Config["ProjectDirectory"] + "/" + prDirs[i];
  console.log("PATH=" + path);
  fs.stat(path + "/project.xml", function (err, stat) {
    if (err == null) {
      console.log("  => PATH=" + path);
    }
  })
}
```

NodeJS loops correctly over the directory, the `console.log()` outputs all the directories correctly, but the code inside the if inside fs.stat() is not called and runs only once at the end of the loop. My console shows this:

```
PATH=(...)/PHP
PATH=(...)/Electron
PATH=(...)/testapp
PATH=(...)/Vala
  => PATH=(...)/Vala/project.xml
```

But the project.xml I'm looking for is in `testapp/` **not** in `Vala/` but `Vala/` is the last entry in `prDirs`.

The code above is my latest attempt, I've tried plenty of other variations and one (I appended an `else` to the `if` inside `fs.stat()`) showed me, that `fs.stat()` actually **gets** invoked, but only the code inside the `if` is not running and the code in the `else` I appended once **was** running.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick fix would be to use `let` instead of `var`, but ultimately, it might be worthwhile to read up on asynchronous function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.stat` is an asynchronous i/o function, so its callback will be called only after the main thread is idle, or in your case, only after the `for` loop is done. Instead of a `for` loop, I suggest iterating the folder in an asynchronous matter. You can use [`async.each`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), [`async.eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries), or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gil Z mention `fs.stat` in async. I would suggest to use `promises` if you want to keep for each loop and make code looks sync.

Here is the example. Works on node v 6.9

```
"use strict";
const fs = require('fs');
let paths = ["tasks", "aaa", "bbbb"];
//method to get stat data using promises
function checkFileExists(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       fs.stat(path + "/project.xml", (err, res) => {
           resolve(err ? "Not found in " + path : "  => PATH=" + path);
       });
   });
}
//create promise array with each directory
let promiseArr = [];
paths.forEach(pathPart => {
    let path = process.cwd() + "/" + pathPart;
    promiseArr.push(checkFileExists(path));
});
//run all promises and collect results
Promise.all(promiseArr)
.then(reslut => {
    console.log(reslut);
})
.catch(e => console.log("Error in promises"));
```

The above code will log this

```
[ '  => PATH=/Users/mykolaborysiuk/Sites/circlemedia/syndic-apiManager/tasks',
  'Not found in /Users/mykolaborysiuk/Sites/circlemedia/syndic-apiManager/aaa',
  'Not found in /Users/mykolaborysiuk/Sites/circlemedia/syndic-apiManager/bbbb' ]
```

Hope this helps.